# @EnableOAuth2Sso does not check if token has expired

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have implemented a gateway to be oauth2 client in front of my resources services and ui . Every thing is working good except when a token expire i receive

```
<oauth>
    <error_description>bfc5a9f6-0537-4ab9-91c1-e756501b429d</error_description>
    <error>invalid_token</error>
</oauth>
```

Checking the log i found out Gateway is considering the user as authenticated as the session already exist

```
2017-06-21 09:17:34.311 DEBUG 32482 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authentication@a80f4caf: Principal: user; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: remoteAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, sessionId=<SESSION>, tokenType=bearertokenValue=<TOKEN>; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ACTUATOR, ROLE_USER
2017-06-21 09:17:34.311 DEBUG 32482 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@1aaae9c5, returned: 1
```

while my Resource service or UI don't

```
2017-06-21 09:17:34.532  WARN 32484 --- [nio-9001-exec-1] o.s.b.a.s.o.r.UserInfoTokenServices      : Could not fetch user details: class org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.UserRedirectRequiredException, A redirect is required to get the users approval
```

Gateway Configuration

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableZuulProxy
public class GatewayApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GatewayApplication.class, args);
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class WebSecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

    }

}

security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      accessTokenUri: http://localhost:9191/uaa/oauth/token
      userAuthorizationUri: http://localhost:9191/uaa/oauth/authorize
      clientId: acme
      clientSecret: acmesecret
    resource:
      user-info-uri: http://localhost:9191/uaa/user
      prefer-token-info: false
zuul:
  ignored-services: '*'
  routes:
    authserver: /uaa/**
    resource-service: /resource/**
    ui:
      path: /ui/**
      strip-prefix: false
```

UI Configuration or Any Resource Server

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableResourceServer
public class UiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UiApplication.class, args);
    }
}

security:
  oauth2:
    resource:
      user-info-uri: http://localhost:9191/uaa/user
server:
  port: 9001
  context-path: /${spring.application.name}
```

What i do expect and trying to do is that gateway check if the token is valid and if it is not redirect the user to login page or use the refresh token to update the token ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking to @dave-syer on gitter he told me that we need to declare `OAuth2RestOperations` inside the gateway as it is not created by default in `spring-boot` and it is needed to request the refresh token in the [OAuth2TokenRelayFilter](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-security/blob/master/spring-cloud-security/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/security/oauth2/proxy/OAuth2TokenRelayFilter.java#L85)

So just adding the below fixed every thing

```
 @Bean
 public OAuth2RestOperations oAuth2RestOperations(OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext, OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails details) {
    OAuth2RestTemplate oAuth2RestTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(details, oauth2ClientContext);
    return oAuth2RestTemplate;
}
```